# What could cause my bathroom exhaust fan to stop working?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom

I've got a Vent fan with heater in the bathroom, and recently the vent fan stopped working while the heater worked fine. Thinking this might be just a bad switch issues, I took the cover plate off the switch and found that the switch itself was working. When in on position there was no voltage reading across the terminals, and when off I got standard 120 reading from the common hot to the heater terminal. From the common hot to the vent fan terminal, I was getting a fluctuating reading from like 60 to 80 volts (and yes my meter was in the AC mode)

the heater has its own fan which still works.

Comment: Is the vent fan hard wired or corded? What reading do you get on the incoming power (from within the housing) with it disconnected\unplugged?

Comment: haven't had time to get a ladder out and take the cover off the unit just had time to take the switch cover off so far and am puzzled by the reading i got at the switch beyond figuring that the switch is good and the hot is good so when i have time my next step is to get inside the heater/vent fan unit it self and take a look there but to all of my understanding of electrical the fluctuating reading from the switch makes no sense on an open circuit

Comment: possibly the fan is kaput. Dust, moisture, hair and stuff blocking the fan from spinning. If it has a fuse its most likley blasted. Fuses in motors are usually not replaceable. Only thing is to take it out, plug it to normal plug. `If (fan != spin) then { replace }`

Answer (score 1):

It may be unsafe to run the heater without a working fan.

Drop ALL the power to the room and remove the guts from the assembly. Usually the fan will have a short cord with a plug. Power it up and try to get it to spin (don't get shocked or bitten).

If it is fail you *might* be able to get a replacement from the manufacturer. IME this is hit or miss; sometimes I end up buying a completely new (same) fan and swap the guts so I don't have to install much. Manufacturers may not sell you replacement parts but they sure will sell you the whole thing...

Don't throw anything away. You may need the squirrel cage off the old fan motor if you *can* find its equivalent.

Verify the outlet in the housing is working properly.

Comment: the heater fan is working it's just the vent fan that doesn't turn on when its switch is turned on but the heater and its fan turn on fine when its switch is flipped

Comment: That's what he's saying. The fan motor is probably bad. It's a VERY common issue. The heater has a completely separate blower motor.

Answer (score -1):

"... the switch it self was working because when in on position there was no voltage reading across the terminals"; In **ON** there **should** be current across the switch;

"... when off i got standard 120 reading from the common hot to the heater terminal"; you should **not** get current in **OFF**.

You cannot measure AC current "from the common hot to the heater terminal" across a switch, you need to bridge from a hot (or switched hot) to a neutral conductor.

I think you may be testing incorrectly, a switch just "makes" or "breaks" the connection of the hot lead. To measure AC voltage you need to contact a neutral conductor with one of your tester leads.

Comment: wasn't measuring current i was measuring voltage because i had a small meter with thin leads i didn't feel it safe to try and measure current through the switch so i measured voltage across it for a simple circuit like most house circuits with an open switch you should have full voltage across it and with a closed switch you should have no voltage across it

Comment: When a switch is in the **open** position, you'll have a voltage potential between the terminals. This is because you have mains voltage at one terminal, and 0 volts (or close to it) at the other. When the switch **closes**, electricity flows from one terminal to the other. This means there's no longer any voltage potential difference between the terminals. So in the case of an **open** switch, you'll measure mains voltage between the terminals. With a **closed** switch, you'll measure 0 volts.

Comment: If you measure from neutral or ground to the feed terminal, you'll always measure mains voltage. If you measure from neutral or ground, to the other terminal. You'll get mains voltage when the switch is closed, and 0 volts when it's open.

Comment: I never suggested that you were attempting to measure current. As @Tester101 states, switch **OPEN** (off) potential exists across the switch, switch **closed** (on) no potential across the switch. **Either way you cannot measure the voltage at any of the hot conductors without a test lead to neutral** (or ground).